# Does not add the response from the server to the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have a function that sends a request to the server to get posts. The response from the server is "200" , but when outputting this array it is empty. I use useEffect so that when I enter the page, it works immediately

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'


function News() {
    let [post, setpost] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        getnews()
    }, [])
    
    async function getnews(){
        let responce =  await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(responce=> setpost(responce.data))
        console.log(post)
    }

    return (<>
        <div className="main">
            <div className="main__name">
                <h1>New</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="main__post">

            </div>
        </div>
    </>);
}
export default News;
```

[image]

Comment: well `post` is still empty when you log it, because you're doing it before the request has finished. Even if you moved the console.log inside the `.then` though, it would still log as empty due to React state updates being async. But it will update on the following render, so if you actually make use of `post` in your rendered output this should work correctly.

Comment: @RobinZigmond now I tried to bring them to the page through .map and lo and behold, it works.